# Can you change the path of a database file?

Tags: anylogic

I have an Excel spreadsheet on my desktop. I pull parameter data from it. I want to move it from my desktop to somewhere else.  How do I do this?

[image: Database Path]

Comment: Move it to the other location and then update the path property to point to that new location.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite but the path in the property window won't allow editing. Only allows toggling between absolute and relative path. I can't type in anything new. If I move the spreadsheet and run the model, I just get errors (was hoping for a dialog box to find it).

Error during model creation:
Error during database initialization
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No sheet named 'PACKLINE2_COMPS can be found. Are you sure of the Excel file path ?
Caused by: No sheet named 'PACKLINE2_COMPS can be found. Are you sure of the Excel file path ?
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during initi

Answer (score 0):

Having something in the Data section as you show in your image means that it's referenced somewhere in your model. In this case you used an Excel object from the connectivity palette.

Your mission is to find that object and change the path there after moving it:
[image: excel file]

On this example, I have an Excel File element called parameters and if I want to change the path, I have to find the file again using the "..." button to the right of File:

When you do that, it automatically changes the path.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe. I looked around to see if I had the Excel object and I don't.  The only way I could get this to work is shown in my Answer, but I still can't easily move the file.

Comment: it's impossible that you don't have the excel object somewhere... you have to look better... or send the model and I will show you where it is

Answer (score 0):

So here's all I could figure out.  I had to change all of the instances where I refer to the database so the Population is "Initially empty".

[image: Population needs to be initially empty]

Once I did this, I deleted the databases and had to save and close the model.  Once I reopened it, the Resource had disappeared. I then moved the Excel file and re-imported it, but I'm sure there's a better way.